# TCL special character \x1

Tags: tcl

I have a problem with TCL string

```
set WORD 128
set CELL_NAME "MCELL_$WORD\x1" 

# real: MCELL_128.. (.. is 2 special characters that I can't paste here)

# expected: "MCELL_128x1"
```

How can I format the string as expected?

Comment: `\x` introduces a hex character code substitution. You probably don't want to use it for a bunch of ugly reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set CELL_NAME "MCELL_${WORD}x1"
```

gives you the expected output.

Other possibilities:

```
set CELL_NAME "MCELL_[set WORD]x1"
set CELL_NAME [format "MCELL_%dx1" $WORD]
```

Documentation:
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), particularily item [[8]](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12).